# Generating violet noise with a specific PSD coefficient

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, random-process

I am trying to generate a time-domain violet noise signal with the following power spectral density (PSD):

$$ S_n(f) = A^2f^2 $$

Unfortunately, I am having trouble finding the right amplitude coefficient to get the correct value of $A$.

I am generating the signal by:

1. Creating a white-noise signal array $\mathcal{w}(t)$ with sample frequency $f_s$ and $\sigma = 1$.
2. Performing numerical differentiation on this signal (which is equivalent to multiplying by $f$ in frequency domain).
3. Multiplying by $1/f_s$ to renormalize after differentiating.
4. Multiplying this signal by the root-mean square value of:

   $$  \begin{aligned} \bar{\mathcal{v}}_n &= \left(\int_0^{f_s/2} S_n(f)
   df\right)^{1/2} = \left(\int_0^{f_s/2} A^2f^2
   df\right)^{1/2} 
   \\
   &= \left(A^2 \frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{f_s}{2}\right)^3
   \right)^{1/2}  
   \\
   &= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{6}}A{f_s}^{3/2} \end{aligned} $$

so the final expression is:

$$ \mathcal{v}(t) = \bar{\mathcal{v}}_n \frac{1}{f_s}\frac{d\mathcal{w}(t)}{dt} $$

My problem is that the resulting PSD from this signal is off by a factor of $\pi$ (or maybe 3?) with respect to the expected response.

Here is my code in `python`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
import allantools as aln
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

rng = np.random.default_rng()

fs = 10e3                         # Sampling freq [Hz]
N = 1e5                           # Number of points
A = 1                             # Amplitude spectral density coefficient of violet noise [a.u./(Hz^(3/2)]
time = np.arange(N)/fs            # time array [s]

vn = np.sqrt(1/3*A**2*(fs/2)**3)  # RMS value of signal [a.u.]

# Time-domain violet noise signal
vn_t = vn*np.diff(rng.normal(size=time.shape[0]+1))

# Compute PSD
f, Sn_f = signal.welch(vn_t, fs, nperseg=2048)

plt.loglog(f,Sn_f)
plt.loglog(f,A**2*f**2,'tab:red')

plt.xlabel('frequency [Hz]')
plt.ylabel('PSD [(A.U.)**2/Hz]')
plt.legend(('Simulated PSD','Expected PSD'),loc='lower right')
plt.xlim([1e1,5e3])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Which results in the following plot:
[image]

These are the results if I divide the simulated PSD by $\pi$:
[image]

My guess is that I am missing something in the differentiation step, as this is for a Gaussian-distributed random process, but after doing a lot of searching, most of the references I see say that either white-noise signals are non-differentiable, or have just some complicated stochastic differential calculus equations that don't really point to anything practical (like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2422857/time-derivative-of-white-noise)).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I know that I could generate the frequency-domain signal and then perform an ifft to get the time-domain signal of interest, but I am asking this question because I am interested in knowing what would be the correct procedure to generating the time-domain signal directly.

Comment: is `np.diff` really the approximation to differentiation you want to make? Because if I remember correctly, it's just `out[i] = in[i]-in[i-1]`, and that might not have the amplitude response you want (i.e., with $f(t)=e^{j\omega t}$,  $\left\lvert\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} f \right\rvert= \omega$, whereas $\lvert\text{numpy.diff}(f) \rvert= \left\lvert e^{j\omega t}-e^{j\omega t}\cdot e^{-j\omega \Delta t}\right\rvert =\left\lvert e^{j\omega t}\left(1-e^{-j\omega \Delta t}\right)\right\rvert=\left\lvert 1-e^{-j\omega \Delta t}\right\rvert\ne \omega$, so this is far from what it should be.)

Comment: A different way to write it $H(\omega) = \frac{1}{2j} e^{-j\omega T/2}\cdot sin(\omega T/2)$, This way you can see the magnitude directly.

Comment: But I don't think that's the problem here. I would take a look at the different scaling option of `signal.welch` and understand the effect of windowing on the scaling. Make sure you get the expected answer for white noise first before trying anything fancy.

Comment: Thanks @Hilmar. I believe there should be no issue with `signal.welch` as I use it quite often for other purposes (including white noise). Your previous comments are quite interesting though. I think the $\sin(\omega T/2)$ might be where the key to the problem might be, but I need to process your comments carefully before drawing conclusions. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, would it be possible for you to point me to a reference where I can see how this differentiation (`out[i] = in[i]-in[i-1]`) corresponds to this transfer function in frequency domain: $H(\omega) = \frac{1}{2j} e^{-j\omega T/2}\cdot sin(\omega T/2)$? I am fairly inexperienced in signal processing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgraded to full answer.

The `diff` function implements the difference equation

$$y[n] = x[n]-x[n-1]$$

The transfer function is simply

$$H(z) = 1 - z^{-1}$$ or

$$H(\omega) = 1 - e^{-j\omega}$$

where $\omega$ is the normalized frequency. We can write this as

$$H(\omega) =  e^{-j\omega /2} \left( e^{+j\omega/2} - e^{-j\omega/2}\right)  = e^{-j\omega /2} \cdot 2  j \cdot \sin(\omega/2) $$

(sorry, I had the factor $2j$ inversed in my original comment).

There are a few things to note here: The linear phase term $ e^{-j\omega/2}$ is equivalent to a half sample delay. That is caused by the fact that the difference is centered around $n = 1/2$ and not around $n = 0$. If you estimate the derivative as $y[n] = x[n+1]-x[n-1]$, that problem would go away (but make other things worse).

For small frequencies we can use $\sin(x) \approx x$ and we'd get

$$H(\omega) \approx  j\omega e^{-j\omega/2}$$

which matches the continuous derivative other than the half sample delay.

At higher frequencies you will run into some sort of aliasing. In order to sample a signal without loss, the signal needs to be bandlimited, which is not the case. When you represent a signal in a computer as an array of numbers, it's discrete, and if it's discrete in one domain it's periodic in the other. Hence, it flattens out at the Nyquist frequency: the frequency domain periodicity enforces that (which is exactly what aliasing is).

## EDIT: matching the amplitudes

I think your goal is to energy-match the signal before and after the spectral shaping. So if $y[n] = A \cdot (x[n]-x[n-1])$ you have

$$\sum y^2[n] = \sum x^2[n]$$

That's really simple if $x[n]$ is white noise. White noise is uncorrelated with itself other than at a lag of zero and specifically we have $r_{xx}[-1] = 0$. That means you are simply subtracting two uncorrelated sequences and the energy of the sum (or difference) is the sum of the energies. Assuming $x[n]$ has a RMS of 1, than $x[n]-x[n-1]$ has a power of 2 or an RMS of $\sqrt{2}$. So the scale factor simply becomes

$$A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Your original method doesn't work because you are using a continuous model to solve a discrete problem. It's simply not applicable.

You can do it in the discrete frequency domain. Let's assume a DFT length of $N$ which is sufficiently large with the transform pairs $x[n] \leftrightarrow X[k]$ and $y[n] \leftrightarrow Y[k]$ . We also assume DFT scaling of $1/\sqrt{N}$ in both directions which preserves Perceval's Theorem between discrete time and frequency.

We have
$$X[k] = 1 \\
Y[k] = Ae^{-j2 \pi/N \cdot k/2} \cdot 2  j \cdot \sin(2\pi/N \cdot k/2) $$

The magnitude squares (or PSDs) are
$$|X[k]|^2 = 1 \\
|Y[k]|^2 = 4A^2\sin^2(2\pi/N \cdot k/2)  = 2A^2(1 - \cos (2\pi/N \cdot k)) $$

The integration turns into a sum, so we get
$$E_x = \sum_0^{N-1} |X[k]|^2 = N \\
E_y = \sum_0^{N-1} |Y[k]|^2 = 2A^2( \sum_0^{N-1} 1 + \sum_0^{N-1}  \cos (2\pi/N \cdot k)) = 2A^2 N $$

Again we see that the one-sample difference of white noise simply doubles the power and that $A = 1/\sqrt(2)$ will match the input power. Your expected PSD becomes

$$|Y[k]|^2 = 2\sin(2\pi/N \cdot k/2) = 1 - \cos(2\pi/N \cdot k)$$

Below is a graph, that shows PSD for both white noise and the diff()'ed version with proper scale. Measurement and expectation match well.

[image]

Code:

```
%% violet noise
fs = 48000; % sample rate
nx = 2^16; % FFT size
% create signals
rng(1); % make it reproducible
x = randn(nx+1,1); % one extra sample for diff()
y = diff(x)/sqrt(2);
x = x(1:nx); % cut down to desired length
% calucalted FFT and PSD 
fx = fft(x)/sqrt(nx);
fy = fft(y)/sqrt(nx);
psdx = fx.*conj(fx); psdx = psdx(1:nx/2+1);
psdy = fy.*conj(fy); psdy = psdy(1:nx/2+1);

% plot it
clf;
k = (0:nx/2)'/nx; % index 0 ... 0.5
fr = k*fs; % frequency vector
semilogx(fr(2:end),10*log10([psdx(2:end) psdy(2:end)]));
hold('on');
grid('on');
xlabel('Frequency in Hz');
ylabel('Level in dB');
set(gca,'ylim',[-100 20]);
set(gca,'xlim',[fr(2) fr(end)]);

% expectation for PSD white is 1 or 0dB
plot(fr,0*fr,'Linewidth',2);
plot(fr,10*log10(1-cos(2*pi*k)),'LineWidth',2);
legend('White actual','Diff actual','White expected','Diff expected', ...
  'Location','SouthEast');
title('white and violet noise, unit power, fs = 48 kHz');
```

Comment: hank you @Hilmar; this makes a lot of sense. Isn't the sampling period missing in the expression though? This has also made me realize a few things: As you rightly pointed out, for 2 (which is the region I'm interested in) this expression is approx to what I am currently using, which means I should be good. However, this still doesn't answer the factor of $\pi$ discrepancy I have.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much for the detailed response.

Comment: By the way @Hilmar, is there any chance you can share your code? Thank you!

Comment: @EdV: Thanks ! fixed